# i'm trying to convert this firebase data to recycle card-view in android

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

[image]

and also send a notification to all user if this database values change like update/insert/delete

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, the idea is:

Fetch the data from firebase as a List.
https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write

Build the recyclerView: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/recyclerview

Catch event when the database change
https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/database-events

Show to notification
https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/build-notification

Also, a ton of tutorial about this problem you can find on the internet
https://proandroiddev.com/firebase-database-paging-android-f59e6dd0dc75